# Pulling Xpath Data from websites from a Table - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pull certain values from different websites. I have all the xpaths in a table, and I want to be able to pull the xpath values from the given websites. I attached a picture of what I want.
[Table w/ Link and Xpath - Red is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8YcH.png)

| Website | Xpath | Web Rec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://cbcmustangs.com/sports/mbkb/2023-24/schedule | /html/body/main/div/div[11/div[3]/div[1]/div[2] | 2-0 |
| https://columbiacougars.com/sports/mens-basketballischedule/2023-24 | /html/body/form/main/article/div[31/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2] | 0-0 |
| https://mbuspartans.com/sports/mens-basketball/schedule/2023-24 | /html/body/form/main/article/div[31/div/div(2]/ul/li[1]/span[2] | 0-0 |
| https://wwuowls.comSports/mens-basketball/schedule/2023-24 | /html/body/form/main/article/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span | 1-0 |
| https://wbueagles.com/sports/mbkb/2023-24/schedule | /html/body/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2] | 0-0 |

I did it with google sheets, but there are so many of them that it is tough to load. I want to be able to do the same in VBA.

Here is something I found on spreadsheetguru about how to pull the titles from pages, but I would like to do it with the xpaths.
`I did it with google sheets, but there are so many of them that it is tough to load. I want to be able to do the same in VBA.

Here is something I found on spreadsheetguru about how to pull the titles from pages, but I would like to do it with the xpaths.

```
Function GetWebpageTitle(cell As Range)
'PURPOSE: Excel Function to pull-in Webpage Title

'SOURCE: www.thespreadsheetguru.com

Dim URL As String
Dim Domain As String
Dim ReceivedHTML As String
Dim TitleTag_Start As Long
Dim TitleTag_End As Long
Dim Title As String
Dim objHttp As Object

'Domain Address to Prefix URL input (optional)
  Domain = "https://www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com"

'Full URL Path
  URL = Domain & cell.Value

'Create HTTP Call
  On Error GoTo InvalidDomain
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHttp.Send ""
    DoEvents
  On Error GoTo 0

'Store URL Page HTML Code
  ReceivedHTML = objHttp.ResponseText

'Search for Title Tags
  TitleTag_Start = InStr(1, UCase(ReceivedHTML), "")

'Isolate Text Within Title Tags (if applicable)
  If TitleTag_Start > 0 And TitleTag_End > 0 Then
    TitleTag_Start = TitleTag_Start + Len("<TITLE>")
    Title = Mid(ReceivedHTML, TitleTag_Start, TitleTag_End - TitleTag_Start)
  End If

'Title Text Cleanup
  Title = Replace(Title, "&amp;", "&")
  Title = Replace(Title, "&#39;", "'")
  Title = Replace(Title, "&quot;", Chr(34))

'Output Result
  GetWebpageTitle = Title

'Reset Object Variable(s)
  Set objHttp = Nothing

Exit Function

'ERROR MESSAGES
InvalidDomain:
  'Output Error Value
    GetWebpageTitle = "Invalid Domain or URL Address"
  
  Reset Object Variable(s)
    Set objHttp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please show your code and sample data as text in OP.

Comment: Hi. I changed it into code instead of a picture!

Comment: What does/doesn't your code do that you need?

Comment: I would like it to pull the data from the link given the xpath. Similar to the importxml function on google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way of using XPath on the results website. Use Selenium for web scraping. When I was developing this code the website timed out at certain times of the day. Download Selenium edgedriver from here - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/   Set Tools > References > Selenium Type Library in the Excel VBE

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub sbCBCMustangs2()
        Dim chr As Selenium.ChromeDriver
        Set chr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = Sheet2.Range("A2").Value
        Dim sXPath As String
        sXPath = Sheet2.Range("B2").Value
        Sheet2.Range("C2").Value = "Not found"
        chr.Start ("edge")
        chr.Get (sURL)
        chr.Window.Maximize
        chr.Wait 10000
        Sheet2.Range("C2").Value = "xA " & chr.FindElementByXPath(sXPath).Text 
' force text value or Excel will interpret 2-1 as 01-Feb...
    End Sub
```